# Error accessing environment hash in Shiny reactive expression. Error Message: Error in get: invalid first argument

Tags: r, shiny

First time poster on Stackoverflow, although I have learnt a ton by browsing. Pretty new to Shiny so I am thinking it may be a simple issue.

Context:

1. wipObj and revObj are both environments used as hashes. wipObj returns DT objects based on client name. revObj returns environment references based on client name, which in turn return ggplots or DTs based on the name of the DT or plot (see below). revObj and wipObj are set by calling a separate .R Script that has a bunch of complex calcs. The basic idea was to allow the user to select a client name and have the plots refresh. But instead of recomputing the plots each time, was looking to pre-compute them and save them in the revObj environment.
2. Server.UI

   input$clientRadio is set from a radio button of client names

   #### No Error (works correctly)

   wipDT <- reactive({
       getWIPTable(input$clientRadio)
   })

   output$wipsnapshot <- DT::renderDataTable({wipDT()})

   #### Does not Work -- **Warning: Error in get: invalid first argument**

   *According to trace it fails on the first get. But when I tried to assign y<- get("All Clients", revObj) [["All]] in the Rstudio console I don't get any issues*

   filtRevObj <- reactive({
       **get(input$clientRadio, revObj)**
   })

   PaidDOlYMObj <- reactive({
       get("PaidDOlYM", filtRevObj())
   })

   output$PaidDOlYM <- DT::renderDataTable({PaidDOlYMObj()})

---- Console output ------------

> class(revObj)
>   [1] "environment"
>
> class(wipObj)
>   [1] "environment"
>
> class(wipObj[["All Clients"]])
>   [1] "datatables" "htmlwidget"
>
> class(revObj[["All Clients"]])
>   [1] "environment"
>
> class(revObj[["All Clients"]][["PaidDOlYM"]])
>   [1] "datatables" "htmlwidget"
>
> y<- get("All Clients", revObj)
>   class(get("PaidDOlYM", y))
>   [1] "datatables" "htmlwidget"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait for `input$clientRadio` to be available with the [`req` function](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/req.html) :

```
# Makes sure reactive value is available
req(input$clientRadio)
# Prints value to console for verification
cat(input$clientRadio)
# Check if it now works
filtRevObj <- reactive({ get(input$clientRadio, revObj) })
```